# how do I target all the even divs inside a div

Tags: html, css

How can I target all the even number divs inside .upcome-events div, basically I want all the even divs with the class name of .event-date ll get different background color than other .event-date divs, I tried this css:

```
.upcome-events .event-date:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

this is my html:

```
                    <div class="upcome-events box">

                        <h4></h4>

                        <div class="event clearfix">
                            <div class="event-date">
                               <h3></h3>
                                <p></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="event-desc">
                                <p></p>
                                <p></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="event clearfix">
                            <div class="event-date">
                               <h3></h3>
                                <p></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="event-desc">
                                <p></p>
                                <p></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="event clearfix">
                            <div class="event-date">
                               <h3></h3>
                                <p></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="event-desc">
                                <p></p>
                                <p></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="event clearfix">
                            <div class="event-date">
                               <h3></h3>
                                <p></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="event-desc">
                                <p></p>
                                <p></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
```

but it is not working for me. any suggestion?

Comment: you should use your brain before using selectors blindly. what is do you consider `even`? obviously it's each `.event` div and most certainly **not** the `.event-date`, since you want to match each `event` and not their inner children.

Comment: thank you, you are right actually my brain must be hanged...this is a very simple parent & child elements combination ...I should look more closely before posting here.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
.upcome-events .event:nth-child(even) .event-date {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: try not. do. there is no try ;)